# Handling oauth intent in multiple activities

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I need to handle oauth intent response in multiple activities, but only in a currently active activity.

Why I need this? I have a login where user confirms ouath when he's logging everything works ok he's redirected to the main activity, but after ouath token expires I need to prompt user to re-authenticating and handle intent in this activity.

When I add following markup to multiple activities.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="..." />
</intent-filter>
```

I get to chose which one I want to handle the oauth result, this is not what I need, I need active activity receiving result automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing: I created single activity that handles intent and then broadcast response to other activities.

On other activies it I added and removed broadcast listener in onStart/onStop callbacks.

I tried added listeners in onResume method, but then I was unable to catch incoming broadcasts since the activity that was broadcasting was still in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RxBus implementation.
First you have to create RxBus class.

```
public class RxBus {
private static RxBus instance;
private PublishSubject<Event> subject = PublishSubject.create();

public static synchronized RxBus getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new RxBus();
    }

    return instance;
}

private RxBus(){}

public void postEvent(Event event){
    subject.onNext(event);
}

public Observable<Event> getEvents(){
    return subject;
}
```

}

And now, you should subscribe to it in BaseActivity or something like this (depends or your project structure).

```
private RxBus rxbus;
private Subscription rxBusSubscription;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rxBus = RxBus.getInstance();
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (shouldSubscribeRxBus()) {
        rxBusSubscription = rxBus.getEvents()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(event -> {
                    if (event.getEventType() == Event.EventType.LOGOUT_USER) {
                        showSessionExpiredDialog();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Now implement you showSessionExpiredDialog as you want.

When you catch exired session call

```
RxBus.getInstance().postEvent(new LogoutUserEvent());
```

You can create your Event classes structure as you want.